# why does irb freak out sometimes when I paste in a script?

Tags: ruby, irb

```
def load_lib
    path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib')
    failures = []
    Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*.rb").each {  |file|
        puts "loading: #{file} ... "
    }
end
```

There's the script. When I put each line in individually, the `load_lib` function is available and works fine. But when I paste it into irb in one big chunk (Ubuntu terminal, Sh Ctrl C) it freaks out at the `Dir.glob(...` line and shows this:

```
Display all 931 possibilities? (y or n)
!
!=
!~
<=>
.... [dozens of lines in this vein]
```

and then the method isn't created at all.

Here's what happens (success) when I paste it in one line at a time:

```
>>  def load_lib
>>     path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib')
>>     failures = []
>> Dir.glob("#{path}/**/*.rb").each {  |file|
?> puts file
>> }
>> end
=> nil
>> load_lib
./lib/alpha_processor.rb
./lib/development_mail_interceptor.rb
./lib/service_processors/beta_processor.rb
```

Is there something about the `[]` or `{}` that irb doesn't like when they are pasted in?

Comment: Another way that irb can err on you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269032/why-rails-can-use-if-as-hash-key-but-not-in-ruby/39271791#39271791

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's because of TAB characters you have in your source file. Indent with spaces. :-)

Comment: More accurately, the tab characters trigger irb's autocompletion.  Which you obviously dont want when pasting in code.  The Ruby community has pretty much standardized on 2 space indentation by now, so please just use that.

Comment: @AlexWayne: thanks for clarifying. Should have done it myself.

Comment: Tab is used for auto-complete in `irb` so sometimes cut and paste will trigger this. I think there's an option for turning it off but I can only find references on how to turn it on.

Comment: Ah, that did it. Strange though, since the tabs were at the beginning of the line. Oh, wait I see it now.

Comment: but there's a reason -- demonstrated here -- to hate tabs