# Why Rails can use `if` as hash key but not in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In pure Ruby irb, one cannot type `{if: 1}`. The statement will not terminate, because irb thinks `if` is not a symbol but instead the beginning of an if statement.

So why can Rails have `before_filter` which accept if as parameters? The guide have codes like:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :normalize_card_number, if: :paid_with_card?
end
```

Same thing happens to `unless` as well.

Comment: I just realized that this exact bug was reported months ago: [Bug #12177: *Using `if:` as symbol in hash with new hash syntax in irb console is not working*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12177)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IRb's parser is well-known to be broken. (In fact, the very bug you encountered was already reported months ago: [Bug #12177: *Using `if:` as symbol in hash with new hash syntax in irb console is not working*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12177).) Just ignore it. There are also other differences in behavior between IRb and Ruby, semantic ones, not just syntactic. E.g. methods defined at the top-level are implicitly `public` instead of implicitly `private` as they should be.

IRb tries to parse the code with its own parser to figure out, e.g. whether to submit it to the engine when you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or wait for you on the next line to continue the code. However, because Ruby's syntax is extremely complex, it is very hard to parse it correctly, and IRb's parser is known to deviate from Ruby's.

Other REPLs take different approaches, e.g. [Pry](http://pryrepl.org/) actually uses Ruby's parser instead of its own.

Comment: Do you have more references of "being well-known to be broken"? I am just curious to want to know if there are relevant discussions about that.

Answer (score 7):

That's an irb issue, not Ruby.

```
bash=> ruby -e "puts({if: 1})"
bash=# {:if=>1}
```

You can use `pry` instead. It will read input correctly.

https://github.com/pry/pry

Answer (score 0):

The code in your example is part of the Rails DSL. What you are actually setting there is a hash which just happens to look a bit like code.

Internally, Rails will evaluate this hash specifying conditions to the `before_save` call.

In a very simplified version, Rails basically does this when saving:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  @before_save_rules = []
  def self.before_save(method, options={})
    @before_save_rules << [method, options]
  end

  def self.before_save_rules
    @before_save_rules
  end

  def save
    # Evaluate the defined rules and decide if we should perform the
    # before_save action or not

    self.class.before_safe_rules.each do |method, options|
      do_perform = true
      if options.key?(:if)
        do_perform = false unless send(options[:if])
      end

      if options.key?(:unless)
        do_perform = false if send(options[:unless])
      end

      send(method) if do_perform
    end

    # now perform the actual save to the database
    # ...
  end
end
```

Again, this is very simplified and just in the spirit of actual code, but this is basically how it works.